# javascript filter missing array

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, find

I try make a reject function find a missing values in a array:

```
var store = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,15,16,18,20,21];
var fullArray= [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21];
function reject(array, iteratorFunction) {
    return array.filter(function(element) {
        return !iteratorFunction(element)});
}
var missingValues = reject(fullArray, function(number){
  return store.find(function(item){return number === item});
}); 
console.log(missingValues);
```

but my result shows:

```
[0,9,10,11,12,13,14,17,19]
```

showing me a 0 in the first value.
why this occurs and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

`store.find` returns the element it finds. If that’s `0`, your `iteratorFunction` will return `0`, and `!0` is `true` because `0` is falsy.

A correct presence check using [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) is even more concise, though:

```
var missingValues = reject(fullArray, function (number) {
  return store.includes(number);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also do as follows in a more concise way;

```js
var store     = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,15,16,18,20,21],
    fullArray = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21],
    result    = fullArray.filter(n => !store.includes(n));
console.log(result);
```

However this would run in O(n.m) so a more efficient way would be;

```js
var store     = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,15,16,18,20,21],
    fullArray = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21],
    result    = fullArray.reduce((t,m) => (!t[m] && t.r.push(m),t), store.reduce((h,n) => (h[n] = true,h),{r:[]})).r;
console.log(result);
```

which runs in O(n + m)